# Fill in missing birthdates in a data frame using a function in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to fill the first data frame using the second dataframe as reference, how can i do this, without using for loop? The image bellow ilustrates what i want to do:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsMpj.png)

Comment: `?dplyr::rows_update` should do it